# Why am I receiving a 'an unhandled exception of type system executionengineexception occurred in system data dll' error?

Tags: c#, dll, datatable, unhandled-exception

I am writing a custom component (DLL) for SQL Server Integration services and when trying to debug the component I receive the following error:

> **An unhandled exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll**

When I run the component without debugging I don't receive this error and the piece of code that sets off this error when debugging is the second line of this code:

```
DataTable table;
table = new DataTable();
```

I have tried running this: 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=30135
but I still get the error.

I also created a simple windows form project with the following code:

```
       DataTable table;
       table = new DataTable();
       table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
       table.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
       table.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
       table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

        table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now);
```

and I don't encounter the error when I'm debugging. Does anyone know why I am getting this error and how to I can debug my code?

Comment: What version of the .NET framework are you targeting?

Comment: @icemanind Targeting 4.0

Comment: @CooperCripps: were you able to figure out the reason behind this problem?

Comment: I get that when I try to start debugging my webapi, but I already have a client trying to talk to it. This somehow stuffs up my dbcontext

Answer (score 4):

Usually this is caused by compiling a 64 bit assembly and trying to use it from a 32 bit process or visa versa.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue exactly same as Cooper Cripps stated, mine is happening when I debugging a application in x64 mode, and that error throws when I reach the conn.Open().

`using(var conn = new SqlConnection(connString)){
    conn.Open();
 }`

but it still works if I did not attach debugger(run with Ctrl+F5). 
Finally this issue was resolved by reset userSettings using below:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv" -resetsettings General

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the Debugging->General option "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" can cause this error if it's checked.  It uses an older debugging engine, and that debugging engine apparently doesn't play nice with stuff in System.Data.dll.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, It was **mcafee antivirus** update issue. And it detected some of my files as a malware